# Upper bound of integral of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

Given X as a random variable with distribution p(x). Then $w_1$ and $w_2$ are conditioned on X.

How to prove:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2P(w_1|x) P(w_2\mid x) P(x)\,dx > \int_{-\infty}^\infty \min[P(w_1\mid x),P(w_2\mid x)] P(x) \, dx > \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(w_1\mid x) P(w_2\mid x) P(x) \, dx $$

Comment: Why should this be true?

Comment: I got it from an engineering textbook, not sure if I interpreted it right though. They say that if replace 2 by any $\alpha>2$ it should be correct

Comment: The second inequality (the one you just added) is trivial. The first one seems ludicrous.

Comment: I got it. There's one more assumption which is $P(w_1|x)+P(w_2|x)=1$. Sorry for my "engineering" math skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion is a consequence of the following fact:

> For every $p$ in $(0,1)$, one has: $2p(1-p)\geqslant\min(p,1-p)\gt p(1-p)$.

To prove this fact, assume without loss of generality that $p$ is in $(0,\frac12]$, then the middle term is $p$, hence one wants to prove that $2(1-p)\geqslant1\gt1-p$, which is trivial.

Now, apply this to $p=P(w_1\mid x)$ and integrate. (Note that the first inequality $\gt$ does not hold and should be replaced by $\geqslant$.)